# Is it possible to play multiple sound files simultaneously (like a mix) on Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

This is the code I am using to play a sound with `AVAudioPlayerNode`. It is just playing the last sound of the beats array. On iPhone, all sounds from the beats array are playing simultaneously with the same function.

```
-(void)playMix{
for (int i = 0; i< mix.beatsArray.count;i++) {
    beat = [[WatchBeatObject alloc] initWithFileName:mix.beatsArray[i].fileName];
    [beat.audioPlayerNode play];
    [beat.audioPlayerNode scheduleBuffer:beat.buffer atTime:nil options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops completionHandler:^{
    }];
}
```

}

N.B: Method `initWithFileName:` handles initializing and creating `AVAudioPlayerNode` and everything needed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does that `WatchBeatObject` has any category option in `AVAudioSession` to set AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient? If yes, set it, they would mix different sound.

Comment: No it doesn't have any category option, it has just AVAudioEngine with AVAudioPlayerNode attached

Comment: @MarcKhairallah Maybe you can try with AVAudioMixerNode instead of AVAudioNode, the mixer can mix multiple inputs to a single output. Quote: Normally, you will want to configure the node’s output format with the same number of channels as are in the files and buffers to be played. Otherwise, channels will be dropped or added as required. It is usually better to use an AVAudioMixerNode to do this.

Comment: Thank you, I already change the app to play sound on phone not on watch. Thank you again for your help